# android:animateLayoutChanges doesn't show view until touched

Tags: android

I'm building an app with a swipe-left to delete function. I've got an undo dialog, so when the user decides to 'undo' a delete, I merely have to bring it on screen by restoring the original X position and making it visible.  The problem is that it doesn't reappear until the view is touched, the scrollView is scrolled, a button touched - almost anything, and then it will appear.

I make my view come back with this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View item = container.getChildAt(i);
            int tag = (int) item.getTag();
            if (tag == deleteTag) {
                item.setX(originalX);
                item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                item.setOnClickListener(snapShopDetailListener);
                item.setOnTouchListener(removeTouchListener);
                item.invalidate(); // force redraw
            }
        }
```

And I place them, programmatically, into a LinearLayout I called 'container' in my Java. Here it is with the animation on;

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/store_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>
```

I tried to invalidate the view and force a redraw, but that didn't help. When it finally appears, everything is in place just like it should be, it just is an empty space until something is touched.

When I turnoff 
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"

then the views don't come in so prettily, but they come in and stay n and I have issues.

Comment: What is originalX? How do you get it? Shouldn't it just be 0?

Comment: Should be,  but just capture that at the ACTION_DOWN to be sure